# respond to jquery event within an angular digest in an angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-promise

I am trying to make this work on the $onInit function in angularJS.

```
popup() {
    this.$log.log("popup clicked...");
}

constructor(
    public $log: ILogService,
    public $timeout: ITimeoutService,
    public $q: IQService,
    public $element: any) {

    // i have tried this
    $element.on("click custom:event", $q.when(() => this.popup()));

    // and this.
    $element.on("click custom:event", $timeout(() => this.popup(), 1000));

    // I have also tried the scope (last resort)
    $element.on("click custom:event", $scope.apply(() => this.popup());
}
```

**In each case the error is:**

> Uncaught TypeError: ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function
>       at HTMLElement.dispatch
>       at HTMLElement.elemData.handle

Is there  a way to correctly create a promise such that the jQuery event is triggered within the angular digest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who might benefit... I was being stupid.

```
    this.$element.on("click", () => $q(() => this.popup()));
```

Comment: The choice of $q is random here. It creates a promise that will never be used. It should be $scope.apply instead.

Comment: It works because $q creates a digest, but the usage of $q is wrong here. There's a typo. It's $scope.$apply, not $scope.apply.